# How can I remap keys on a headless mac?

Tags: keybindings

At the moment I'm remotely accessing my mac via logmein.  I'm trying to remap Command to Control via system preferences.  However every time I try to do this it keeps resetting to the default.  As best I can tell this is because there is no keyboard plugged in.  Is there some way to remap the keys without a keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

you can use KeyRemap4MacBook

http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

there are also predefined settings to achieve what you need:

[image]